# Count values that aren't blank or N/A - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I had figured out this formula to count all those values that weren't blank, but the system updated the template and now besides blank it has also "N/A" values.

How can I transform this

```
=COUNTIF('R Plan'!XT2:XT3658,"<>")
```

To test if besides NOT blank also test for NOT N/A

Because I tried this

```
=COUNTIF('R Plan'!XT2:XT3658,"<>" OR "<>N/A")
```

and I'm getting a message that we found an error on your formula

Comment: are you looking for vba or a formula? your question states vba

Comment: @jellz77 formula to include in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using >=XL2007 then you can use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS('R Plan'!XT2:XT3658,"<>",'R Plan'!XT2:XT3658,"<>N/A")
```

If you're using <=XL2003 then you can use:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF('R Plan'!XT2:XT3658,"<>"),-COUNTIF('R Plan'!XT2:XT3658,"N/A"))
```

Count the number that are not empty and minus those that have N/A.

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('R Plan'!XT2:XT3658<>"")*('R Plan'!XT2:XT3658<>"N/A"))
```

Comment: Such an easy solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use VBA, then this will work for you,

Put this in a cell and choose your range `=COUNTBLANKS(B1,A1:A21)` , `B1` being the value you want to count and the second range is the range you want to count how many times that value occurs.

Add a module and paste this function in it.

```
Function COUNTBLANKS(r As Range, rng As Range) As Long

   Dim x
   Dim c

     x = rng
        For Each c In x
           If c = r Then
              COUNTBLANKS = COUNTBLANKS + 1
           End If
        Next c


End Function
```